# Is there any interactive console for some strong language for everyday work of processing strings?

Tags: ide, console, text-processing

starting to work as an IT man lately

with some programing background,

there are so many occasions where there's a need for processing large amount of data.

mainly strings i guess..

for example:

- there's 2 large sets of lines, and we need all the lines in both of the sets
- replacing one or more white characters in a row, to one line break...
- taking the 4th to 7th character of each line and print them in one line with comma as a delimiter

these are not the best examples, but generally any kind of parsing, manipulating and query of texts.

it's very often that the task is extremely easy in any programing language, but it is just to frustrating to open the IDE of such language....

i'm looking to some way to write code (with intelisence/autocomplete), in an easy fast window...... with simple input and output textboxes....

do you understand my need? can you think of anything that can help?

i know some of the problems can be solved using excel.. but i really prefer some good old programing.... unless someone is strongly believe i'm wrong.

if i will build something myself, there will be an option to add any amount of unlimited multiline textboxes. they'll be automatically named, although the name is changeable (the names will be the the name of the variables).

you can as well add any number of output textboxes that have names...

and you have the editor window, in which you write the procedure..... and it will have some interactive intelisence like interface...

can you see what i'm saying? do you know anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [Python](http://www.python.org/) would be fine for this.

Has an interactive keyboard interface, quite nice abstraction facilities,
and strings as objects with good libraries for processing such strings.

Comment: i thought about Python.... but i don't know any nice ide with some nice autocomplete (since i don't really know python for good)

Comment: Like most langauges, if you use it a bit you know it a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a lot of what you want can be handled with **regular expressions** using sed, awk, or perl in a standard console. Autocomplete will be pretty limited, but your scripts will be short anyway - to deal with your third case above, for example:

```
sed 's/^...\(....\).*/\1/g' < input.txt | tr "\n" ',' > output.csv
```

What you can do is use an **interactive regex tester**. There's many online like [this one](http://regex.powertoy.org/).

You could also look into tools like [Data Wrangler](http://vis.stanford.edu/wrangler/) from Stanford, which are designed to be more accesible but as powerful as traditional shell tools.

(Note that your first issue - intersecting sets of lines - is a bit different, and would be solved in the shell with `comm`. [This page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) has a good explanation of how to use comm to perform set operations like "all the files in this file not in this file" or "only the files in this file also in this other file".)